# Using synced folder (dropbox, gdrive, syncthing etc) as database

Tags: javascript, git, sqlite, dropbox, electron

I want to write notes app in electronjs that will be completely filebased and will be service agnostic (wont use dropbox api for example) but it will be able to sync.

I cant simply sync sqlite db for example because it will break when more people edit it at the same time.

Is there any database solution that can do that out of the box (and works with electronjs?). What would be good aproach?

My other ideas:

1. Use git implementation in js (Gitlet, git-js) with some sort of auto commit? Maybe it would also save history? :)
2. Use not synced database for each client but use sync just for syncing changes and implement some sort of query for each client?

Thank you for ideas!

Answer (score 0):

No there is no database solution that can handle multiple people editing something at the same time "out of the box", because no database can see into your app and realize that two people are busy on the same data, nor magically realize how to resolve conflicts.

Collaborative editing and/or conflict resolution is not trivial! Probably what you want to do is have a "checkout" system whereby when one user opens a file or note, it's marked read-only for all other users until that user has saved or "check in" their changes (But then what happens when a user wanders off from their PC with a file open in edit mode?  Do you see how even this simplest solution is going to get complicated?)

Apologies if I have misunderstood the question.  If so, please let us know what your desired spec is.

Comment: You are right, it is a hard problem and i am asking probably naive question since there is no silver bullet. 

For future reference there is an effort https://github.com/attic-labs/noms of database that could help with this.

Comment: When its such a common problem, i wonder is there any literature on this? Maybe some book dealing with version controling and databases?